# Is it safe to sign a jwt in mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, oauth-2.0, jwt

When the user enters username and password into an mobile app( iOS ,Android or windows app)it calls a thirds party oAuth login web service which responds back with oAuth access token and refresh token. Now the app generates a JWT and signs with a Secret key stored in the app. This jwt is used for authentication on a set of In house APIs

In this context,  is it safe to trust this AUTH model? Since in-general JwT are generated on the server side , so the integrity is maintained.

What are the pitfall of signing a jwt in mobile apps? Will the secret signing key stored in the apps ever gets compromised ?

Comment: A better place for this question would be: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

> Will the secret signing key stored in the apps ever get compromised?

Yes, the signing key can get compromised. This can be done by decompiling your app executable.

Instead of storing the token in a sqlite database or local file, you can make use of the secure storage that each of these platforms provide.

For iOS, you can simply use the [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TP9), a secure storage intended for this purpose.

As for Android, a similar functionality is provided by the [Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore).